# Section height in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was looking at [this code](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-new-age) and there is something I don't understand. You can [live preview](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-new-age/) this website.
My question is : How is the height of the "Download" section (All the buzz, the yellow one) set ?

I looked in the css but didn't find anything relative to the height of this section.

Also I know that it's a pattern in the header but is there a trick to make the background-image not to move when resizing the page? (Like it does with the pattern ? Cropped)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The height isn't really set. The height is coming from the size of the content plus padding: 150px 0; set on the container. So the height is content plus 150px top and bottom padding.